# Is there really no spell check on the built-in keyboard?

Tags: spell-check

I am a new Motorola Droid4 (Verizon) user (from a blackberry). Moto is telling me that there is no spell check on the built-in keyboard, only on the Mutli-touch keyboard.

Is that right?

Comment: When you say "built-in keyboard" do you mean the physical one as opposed to the soft (on-screen) keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

If you have your keyboard input method set to Multi-touch Keyboard, then you should continue to get word suggestions even when you have the hardware keyboard open and are using it. If you have your keyboard input method set to Swype, you won't receive suggestions.